# Install php via rpm

Tags: apache-2.2, php

We have a situation where on a server (centos 5.4) where we will deploy an application, apache has been compiled and installed from source.

On my devel server I was using rpms for both apache and php 5.3.

Is it possible to use the php rpms without installing an rpm for apache, but rather use the compiled one on the server?

Is that possible or must I compile php too? I really would like to avoid that

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally try to avoid mixing a compiled program with the rpm ones- as they require changing where each program looks for components of the other (and env Variable setting).

You may find it easier to compile php than try to use the rpm version - which you are most likely going to have to munge with for hours until php plays nice with the source-built apache you have. I *think* you may actually find it easier to build php than try to mess with the paths in the pre-compiled version - but I have always done the rpm builds of both apache and php (which works fine).

Again my rule is don't mix local build versions and centos rpms - that is bound to cause you headaches.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply.
I guess I will have to go for it